# How to get javafx method to show wait cursor & return result from a completed task

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to display a wait cursor in javafx while a method is doing a task on a non-fx thread. Most importantly, I need the method to return the result of the task (in this case a list). My code returns the empty initial list and not the result of the task. How do I fix it? Thanks.

```
public static final List<String> getCodeList(Scene scene){
  List<String> list = new ArrayList();
  Task<List<String>> task = new Task<List<String>>() {
     @Override
     public List<String> call() {
        final String CPT_QUERY = "SELECT code, description FROM code_table ORDER BY code";
        List<String> codes = new ArrayList();
        try (Connection connection = Network.getCurrentConnection();
                PreparedStatement getCodes = connection.prepareStatement(CPT_QUERY);) {
           ResultSet resultSet = getCodes.executeQuery();
           while (resultSet.next()){
              codes.add(resultSet.getString("code") + "  " + resultSet.getString("description"));
           }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
           sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return codes;
     }
  };
  scene.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
  task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
     list.addAll(task.getValue());
     scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
  });
  new Thread(task).start();
  return list;
```

}

Comment: The result of the task is not available until the task completes. If you want this method to return the result of the task, it would have to block execution until the task is complete (basically removing any point in running it in a background thread to begin with); if the method is being invoked on the FX Application Thread you really don't want to do that because the UI will be unresponsive until the method completes. Why do you want the method to return the result? You already have a callback (`setOnSucceeded`) that is invoked when it is complete, why not just use that to do what you need?

Comment: I use the task to display the wait cursor on the FX Application Thread so the user doesn't think that the application has hung during a long running task. I need the result of the task in another method (that calls getCodeList) and which must return something to yet another method. At some point, I need to figure out how to return something from a method that contains a task. If there is no need for a return value, everything works great. Many thanks.

Comment: You're asking for something that is clearly not possible. Your `getCodeList` method returns *before* the task completes, so when it returns, the list is not yet computed. There's no way to return it there. If you need to do something with that list, you have to do it in the `onSucceeded` handler, which is invoked when the task finishes (and consequently, when the list is computed).

Comment: It might not be possible. So far, that is true for me. It strikes me that the essence of the question is: Is there a way, perhaps using the Condition or Executor(s) classes, to delay the return until the task is complete?

Comment: Well, yes, as I said in my first comment, you can block until the task completes. But then there is no point in using a task and a background thread at all; it will behave exactly the same way as if you don't put it into a background thread. I don't really get what you are trying to do. If you need to do something with the list when it is computed, you have already shown the solution for that: do it in the `onSucceeded` handler.