# How to ensure sequential and complete execution of 2 statements in Java method

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition

I have a 2 statement method in Java 8. The first statement takes a relatively long time to execute, and importantly, **can't** return a value. The second statement is quite quick. How do I execute and complete the first statement and ensure that the second statement does not execute until the first is done? A code snippet would be much appreciated.

```
public static Object returnMyClassFieldValue() {
  setMyClassField(); // long running; can't return a value
  return MyClass.valueOfMyField; // very quick
```

}

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got, exactly?  If `setMyClassField` blocks, then the execution of that method should be sequential.  If `setMyClassField` doesn't block, please add more details to your question so that you can get a more concise answer.

Comment: Unless setMyClassField() explicitly does something asynchronously then it will run to completion before the second statement is executed. What does setMyClassField do?

Comment: Unless you've done something special, what you've described is exactly how that code statement will work. Off the top of my head, if you're executing something in command line or possibly sending a message to a database without awaiting a response, that might skip a beat, but otherwise, if you're just using plain old Java, you're covered.

Comment: The second statement will not execute until the first is completed. Also, it is not very clear what the purpose of this method is. It looks like a getter, which is first setting the value. Ideally, there should be separate setter and getter methods!

Comment: setMyClassField gets a connection to a database and then obtains a result set. It does this in a Task in an FX application so that it can be moved off the FX-Application thread and a wait cursor can be displayed.

Comment: If you want synchronous (i.e. wait-til-complete) behaviour, then running it in a separate thread seems kind-of pointless ;)

Comment: The reason is to display a Wait cursor, which needs to be done by running the task on another non-FX application thread

Comment: this seems like a bug in java.

Answer (score 1):

This code is executing sequentially, so the first statement gets executed first and after the statement finished the next gets executed.

The methodcall

```
setMyClassField()
```

returns after the method finished. So there is no additional code needed to run the code sequential.

If you want to run the method in a separate thread, you can use Threads and use the method

```
join()
```

to wait for execution or you use Thread Pools.

Threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Thread Pools: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Conclusion:
You have nothing to do to run the second statement after the first one.

If that answeres your question.

Comment: join() works almost perfectly, except that it seems to kill the display of my wait cursor. Please see my comments above. Many thanks.

Comment: Since I got stuck in Swing, I'm not a real FX pro, but what do you mean with "kill the wait cursor"? Is it disappearing? The logical structure is the following: Display the wait cursor, start the thread, join the thread and after the join just reset the cursor. I hope that's helpful for you.

Comment: My underlying code is displayed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780383/how-to-get-javafx-method-to-show-wait-cursor-return-result-from-a-completed-ta   If I run the code as is, as expected an empty list is returned but the cursor changes to wait and then back to default. If I replace new Thread(task).start(); with 
      Thread t = new Thread(task);
      t.start();
      t.join();

Comment: My underlying code is displayed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780383/how-to-get-javafx-method-to-show-wait-cursor-return-result-from-a-completed-ta   If I run the code as is, as expected an empty list is returned but the cursor changes to wait and then back to default. If I replace Thread(task).start(); with 
      Thread t = new Thread(task);
      t.start();
      t.join();  then the list returns properly but the cursor never changes from the default. Sorry for the formatting, but I haven't quite figured out how to properly comment yet